# EarlGrey possibility to work with multiple accessibility labels or text

Tags: ios, ui-testing, earlgrey

I would like to know if there is a possibility to use in EarlGrey something like

> [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityLabel(@"Log
>   in")]
>        performAction:grey_tap().elementByIndex(0)]

(either with `grey_accessibilityLabel` or `grey_text`)

Very often in our APP exist situations where multiple elements could be found, need a solution to prevent it.

I know that is better to use Accessibility ID to do not face such problems but current state of the APP is that it doesn't have any IDs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked a similar question a while back -

[EarlGrey - How do I check if multiple objects are being shown on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448041/earlgrey-how-do-i-check-if-multiple-objects-are-being-shown-on-the-screen)

EarlGrey encourages using unique matchers for finding elements since using elementByIndex() can cause issues if the order isn't always maintained. You could also write a custom matcher that performs the checks you need as is highlighted in the answer.

Comment: if you have multiple elements matching but only one of them is visible on screen, you can combine the matcher with grey_sufficientlyVisible() to match just the visible element.